# How to remove "end of non-void function" error in c++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I made a program which has the following function:

```
int f(long long int arr[], long long int x, long long int y)
{
    long long int i = x, j = y;
    if(lookup[i][j] == 0)
    {
        if(i == j)
            lookup[i][j] = arr[i];
        else
            lookup[i][j] = min(f(arr, i, j-1), arr[j]);
    }
    else
        return (lookup[i][j]);
}
```

`min()` is also a defined function.

When I compiled the code it throws an error:

> `control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]`

How could I possibly remove this error?

Comment: return some value via `return` statement regardress of value of `lookup[i][j]`.

Comment: Currently, if your code enters the `if` block, nothing will be `return`-ed. Fix this issue and the error will go away.

Comment: The error should be pretty clear: you can reach the end of the function without encountering a `return` of an `int` (your `true` clause of the `if` does not return a value, thus the error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return some value via `return` statement regardress of value of `lookup[i][j]`.

For example, return `0` because I don't know the correct value to return.

```
int f(long long int arr[], long long int x, long long int y)
{
    long long int i = x, j = y;
    if(lookup[i][j] == 0)
    {
        if(i == j)
            lookup[i][j] = arr[i];
        else
            lookup[i][j] = min(f(arr, i, j-1), arr[j]);
        return 0; /* add this line */
    }
    else
        return (lookup[i][j]);
}
```

Alternatively, I guess the function should be like this:

```
int f(long long int arr[], long long int x, long long int y)
{
    long long int i = x, j = y;
    if(lookup[i][j] == 0)
    {
        if(i == j)
            lookup[i][j] = arr[i];
        else
            lookup[i][j] = min(f(arr, i, j-1), arr[j]);
    }
    /* remove else here */
    return (lookup[i][j]);
}
```

Comment: Note that the 2 versions are different as the first one returns `0` instead of the new computed lookup value.

Comment: @Jarod42 for me the second function worked very well.